# ThreeJS camera.lookAt() has no effect, is there something I'm doing wrong?

Tags: javascript, macos, google-chrome, 3d, three.js

In Three.js, I want a camera to be pointed at a point in 3D space.

For this purpose, I tried using the `camera.lookAt` function like so:

```
camera.lookAt(new THREE.Vector3(-100,-100,0));
```

However, I found out that the call has no effect whatsoever. It just does nothing at all. I tried changing the numbers in the vector, and I always get the same look on screen, when it should be changing.

I just found now that if I remove the `THREE.TrackballControls` I have in my code, the `camera.lookAt()` works as it should. Is there something wrong with how I use THREE.TrackballControls? This is how I initialize them:

```
    controls = new THREE.TrackballControls( camera, renderer.domElement );

    controls.rotateSpeed = 10.0;
    controls.zoomSpeed = 1.2;
    controls.panSpeed = 0.2;

    controls.noZoom = false;
    controls.noPan = false;

    controls.staticMoving = true;
    controls.dynamicDampingFactor = 1.0;

    var radius = 5;
    controls.minDistance = radius * 1.1;
    controls.maxDistance = radius * 100;

    controls.keys = [ 65, 83, 68 ]; // [ rotateKey, zoomKey, panKey ]*/
```

And then in my render function I do:

```
function render() {
  controls.update();
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
}
```

Documentation on Three.js is pretty scarce, so I thought I'd ask here. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Show us more code. Take at look at this simple sample: http://jsfiddle.net/TE5bM/

Comment: do you have an update loop in which you re-render the scene ? it sounds like you're not updating/rendering.

Comment: @Juan George : I am calling .lookAt() when I set up the scene, before anything is rendered, so my call should have an effect. However, I think I just found the problem; I have THREE.TrackballControls in my code, which I think is interfering with what I tell .lookAt(), because when I remove the THREE.TrackballControls, the .lookAt() function works as it should. What am I doing wrong with THREE.TrackballControls?

Comment: @GeorgeProfenza Juan : I've also put up the code here : https://github.com/houbysoft/js-pdb/blob/master/js-pdb.js with the corresponding HTML at https://github.com/houbysoft/js-pdb/blob/master/index.html

Comment: are you using latest version. There is somethings on changelog.

Comment: @emrah: Yes, I have http://mrdoob.github.com/three.js/build/Three.js

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Looking at the source code of [`THREE.TrackballControls`](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/src/extras/controls/TrackballControls.js), I figured out that I can make the camera look where I want by setting `trackballControls.target` to the `THREE.Vector3` I want it to look at, and then rerendering the scene.

Comment: Thanks! I've googled for the answer for like forever, finally!

Comment: Correct answer! Set controls.target = new THREE.Vector3(1500, 500, 0); where 1500, 500, 0 is my desired target to look at

Comment: Yes, precisely the issue I'm facing and for which I posted a new quesiton [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26557252/inverse-of-camera-lookat). In my case, manually changing the source code of `THREE.OrbitControls` by initializing its `target` property to the same vector passed to `camera.lookAt()` is **not** feasible, I'd rather come up with an inverse function so I could write something like `target = getLookAtVectorFor(camera)` and never have to change `OrbitControls.js`'s source code every time I change the lookAt vector of my camera.

Comment: Same here, searched the result for literally  two days! wanted to change the camera lookat but got no result until this answer.

Comment: With revision 88 R88 the issue went away.

Comment: This is October 2023 and I use v0.157.0. But it is still a riddle how get camera and OrbitControls working together. As soon as orbitControls is a assigned a target, it actually stops working...

Answer (score 12):

Yes Please beware... It seems that having THREE.TrackballControls or THREE.OrbitControls seems to override the camera.lookAt function as your are passing in your camera when you instantiate an instance of the controls.  You might want to get rid of the controls and then performing camera.lookAt() or tween your camera some other way to verify that the controls are having a overriding effect on your Camera.  I googled for a while why camera.lookat() seemed to have no effect.

Answer (score 9):

In my opinion, we are not supposed to mess with the original code. I found a way around to achieve the objective of looking at any particular point.
After having declared your "***control***" variable, simply execute these two lines of code:

```
// Assuming you know how to set the camera and myCanvas variables
control = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, myCanvas);

// Later in your code
control.object.position.set(camX, camY, camZ);
control.target = new THREE.Vector3(targetX, targetY, targetZ);
```

Keep in my mind that this will switch the center of the focus to your new target. In other words, your new target will be the center of all rotations of the camera. Some parts will be difficult to look at as you became familiar to manipulate the camera assuming the default center. Try zoom in as much as you can and you will have a sense of what I am saying
Hope this help.

Comment: This answer helped me.  If you have `OrbitControls`, `TrackballControls`, etc in your visualization, you should use the `controls.target` property instead of `camera.lookAt`.

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out. To prevent `THREE.TrackballControls` or `THREE.OrbitControls` from overriding `camera.lookAt` upon initialization, you need to change the line that sets the control's `target` property to equal the *sum* of the `camera.position` vector and the `camera.getWorldDirection()` vector, instead of how it's currently implemented using a `new THREE.Vector3()` (which defaults to `(0, 0, 0)`).

So, for [`THREE.TrackballControls`](http://threejs.org/examples/js/controls/TrackballControls.js), change line 39 to:

```
this.target = new THREE.Vector3().addVectors(/*new line for readability*/
    object.position, object.getWorldDirection());
```

Same goes for [`THREE.OrbitControls`](http://threejs.org/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js), on line 36.
I actaully haven't tested it on `TrackballControls.js` but it does work on `OrbitControls.js`. Hope this helps.

Comment: If you don't want to override the source code, you can update your controls target in the render loop

Answer (score 1):

Here's an alternative solution: create an object (i.e. cube) with 0 dimensions.

```
var cameraTarget = new THREE.Mesh( new THREE.CubeGeometry(0,0,0));
```

In the render function set the camera.lookAt to the position of the cameraTarget.

```
function render() {
    camera.lookAt( cameraTarget.position );
    renderer.render( scene, camera );
}
```

Then just move cameraTarget around as you wish.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem and was able to make it work by using OrbitControls.target. Below is what I did after declaring a controller.

```
    controller = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
    controller.addEventListener('change', renderer.domElement);
    controller.target = new THREE.Vector3(0, 1, 0);
```