# camera.lookAt not called when THREE controls are being used

Tags: controls, three.js

I am working on a program, that uses THREE.RollControls, when the user goes too far away from the center of the screen, they tend to get lost, so I am working on creating a function that reorients them, facing the center of the scene.

What I had intened to do was simply call the following:

```
camera.lookAt(scene.position)
```

However, this has no affect. From what I was reading on different stack overflow questions specifically this: 
[ThreeJS camera.lookAt() has no effect, is there something I'm doing wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10325095/threejs-camera-lookat-has-no-effect-is-there-something-im-doing-wrong)

It seems like their solution was to do the camera position change using the controls, rather then changing the camera itself.

I do not believe there is any 'Target' in the Roll Controls, so I don't know how I can reset where the camera is looking at based on a THREE.Vector3() Is there a simple way to do this, or will I basically have to:

So far I have 'attempted' to do the follow:
- Calculate the difference of position of the camera with the position of the scene. 
- Normalize this vector
- Subtract it from the direction forward of the camera
- use this vector in  controls.forward.add(thisVector)

but this doesn't do at all what I want (probably because I have no idea what I'm doing)

Thank you in advance for your time!

Isaac

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The same thing bugged me too about the RollControls but I took a different approach in solving the problem. Since the controls are in the example code (in r55) you can modify the controls, as they are not part of the core library. You can see my modifications at http://www.virtuality.gr/AGG/EaZD-WebGL/js/three.js/examples/js/controls/RollControls.js
I introduced a local variable called mouseLook because I could not use the this.mouseLook. I initialized it to false and I only make it true when there is a button press i.e. when navigating in the scene. That solved my problem.

Comment: Absolutely Fantastic Solution!