# Inverse of camera.lookAt()

Tags: javascript, camera, three.js

I googled far and wide but I haven't found the solution to what I think to actually be a pretty common situation. Say I have a `THREE.PerspectiveCamera` initialized to look at a certain point in space:

```
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, 2, 0.1, 100);
var target = new THREE.Vector3(1, 2, 3);
camera.lookAt(target);
```

Now, later on in the code I'd like to be able to find out the coordinates of `target` by simply querying `camera`.
I tried what suggested in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15696963/three-js-set-and-read-camera-look-vector), adapting it to my own scenario:

```
var vector = new THREE.Vector3();
vector.applyQuaternion(camera.quaternion);
console.log(vector);
```

But it logs a vector of coordinates `(0, 0, 0)` instead of the correct coordinates (which, in my example, should be `(1, 2, 3)`).
Any insights? Cheers.

**EDIT:**
Ok so I'm going to try to contextualize here, so as to justify why MrTrustworthy's solution is unfortunately not applicable in my scenario. I'm trying to tweak the `THREE.OrbitControls` library for my purposes, since I noticed that when using it, it overrides whichever position the camera was looking at originally. This has also been reported [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21922316/1154866). Basically, on line 36 of `OrbitControls.js` (I'm using the version which can be found [here](http://threejs.org/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js)) `this.target` is initialized to a `new THREE.Vector3()`; I found out that if I manually set it to equal the same vector I use as argument of `camera.lookAt()` everything works just fine: I can start panning, orbiting and zooming the scene from the same POV I would see the scene from if I didn't apply the controls. Of course, I cannot hard-code this information into `OrbitControls.js` because it would require me to change it every time I want to change the initial "lookAt" of my camera; and if I were to follow MrTrustworthy's suggestion I would have to change line 36 of `OrbitControls.js` to read like this: `this.target = object.targetRef` (or `this.target = object.targetRef || new THREE.Vecotr3()`), which is also too "opinionated" (it would always require `object` to have a `targetRef` property, whereas I'm trying to stick to using only three.js's existing object properties and methods). Hope this helps get a better understanding of my case. Cheers.

Comment: Quaternions only model rotations, so if your camera is not at the origin then you'll also need to compensate for its translation. I expect you'll also need to invert the camera's quaternion.

Comment: Also note that there are infinite solutions to the problem. Technically the camera is looking at any point along its central axis.

Comment: Also, the answer in the SO post you linked to said to do this: `var vector = new THREE.Vector3( 0, 0, -1 );`

Comment: @DrewNoakes, you have a point (actually, you have infinite points! ;)), I could settle for one point thought; if my camera is in `(1, 1, 0)` and was originally looking at `(1, 0, 0)` (straight down along y-axis), the algorithm I'm looking for could as well provide me with point `(1, -1, 0)` for all I care, since setting `camera.lookAt(new THREE.Vector3(1, -1, 0))` would have the same effect as `camera.lookAt(new THREE.Vector3(1, 0, 0))`, right?

Comment: @WestLangley, it seems to me that using `THREE.Vector3(0, 0, -1)` requires some previous knowledge of where the camera *should* be looking at, whereas in my case (see edits) the library which receives the camera object knows nothing about the vector originally passed to `camera.lookAt()` (and shouldn't be fed any additional information which is not deducible simply from the camera itself). Anyhow, for the sake of it I tried using `var vector = new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, -1)` but still no dice: after applying the camera's quaternion to it, it points to the origin rather than the point `(1, 2, 3)`.

Comment: For one thing, use http://threejs.org/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js, and when learning or debugging, use the un-minified version http://threejs.org/build/three.js.

Comment: @WestLangley thanks for the heads up on `OrbitControls.js`, I've downloaded the version you linked; as for three.js, I was already using the un-minified version. Still not working though: if I have a camera looking at a certain point in space, as soon as I add orbit controls to it (due to automatic update upon construction: `OrbitControls.js:654`) the camera's target gets reset to `(0, 0, 0)`. Kinda silly, if you ask me, to have `this.object.lookAt(this.target)` (`OrbitControls.js:292`) where `this.target = new THREE.Vector3()` (`OrbitControls.js:36`) instead of deducing point from object.

Comment: Btw, re-edited my previous edit now that I changed version of `OrbitControls.js` as per @WestLangley's comment.

Comment: `controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(...); controls.target.copy( target );` or `controls.target.set( x, y, z );`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out and wrote my solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26597376/1154866). Since the issue affects both [`THREE.TrackballControls`](http://threejs.org/examples/js/controls/TrackballControls.js) and [`THREE.OrbitControls`](http://threejs.org/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js), the solution involves applying a slight change to both those files. I wonder if it can be considered a valid change and make its way to rev. 70; I will issue a PR on github just for the sake of it :)
Thanks to all those who pitched in.

Answer (score 1):

If your only usecase is "I want to be able to access the camera-targets position via the camera object", you could just put a reference into the camera object.

```
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, 2, 0.1, 100);
var target = new THREE.Vector3(1, 2, 3);
camera.lookAt(target);
camera.targetRef = target;

//access it
var iNeedThisNow = camera.targetRef;
```

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately I cannot do that. See my latest edit to get an understanding of why. :)

Answer (score 1):

well you could put the object in parent, have parent lookat, and have the child object rotated 180 degrees. That's the quick noob solution